# before_save callback is not being triggered on rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails

While running a test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe DailyTask, type: :model do
  context 'crud' do
    [...]
  end

  context 'validations' do
    let(:task) { create(:task) }

    it 'duplicated task, fails' do
      2.times do
        DailyTask.create(task: task, date: Date.today) 
      end
      expect(DailyTask.count).to eq(1)
    end
  end
end
```

A `before_save` callback is to be triggered, as shown:

```
class DailyTask < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :task

  validates_presence_of :date

  before_save :is_there_a?

  def is_there_a?
    DailyTask.where(date: self.date, task_id: self.task_id).empty?
  end
end
```

However, it does not seem to be triggered. Already tried changing it to `before_validation` to no avail. This is the kind of stupid error you don't see unless someone points it out.

**EDIT**: pasted an older version of the code where `before_validation` was called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `before_save` callback **is** being called. (Try adding a debugger in the method, and see!) But it's not doing what you want it to - there is a bug in your code.

To fix the code, you need to **add a validation error** if the check fails. (Your current method just checks if a task exists; it doesn't actually *do anything* with that information.)

You could write it something like this:

```
validate :is_there_a?

def is_there_a?
  if DailyTask.where(date: self.date, task_id: self.task_id).any?
    errors.add(:date, 'already exists for this task')
  end
end
```

Or, you could just use rails' [built-in uniqueness validation method](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of), *with a scope*:

```
validate_uniqueness_of :date, scope: :task_id
```

Alternatively, if you prefer, you could also [combine both validation rules](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) into a single line of code:

```
validates :date, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :task_id }
```

---

As a separate *suggestion*, I would personally write this test a little differently. Instead of:

```
it 'duplicated task, fails' do
  2.times do
    DailyTask.create(task: task, date: Date.today) 
  end
  expect(DailyTask.count).to eq(1)
end
```

You could consider writing it to more explicitly test the validation:

```
it 'duplicated task, fails' do
  DailyTask.create(task: task, date: Date.today)
  duplicate_daily_task = DailyTask.new(task: task, date: Date.today)
  expect(duplicate_daily_task).not_to be_valid
end
```

You could then also verify *why* the duplicate task is considered "invalid". Also, you may wish to consider using a [factory](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot_rails) to create the record, rather than the rails class directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Will take your suggestions to use.